# Viper4Android and OxygenOS 2.1.1 OnePlus 2

Tags: audio, oneplus-two

Does V4A finally work with OxygenOS that comes preinstalled with OnePlus 2? I managed to get it to install but the sound is very distorted, also whenever I try to open V4A it crashes Google Play Framework and other apps. I managed to uninstall the driver by rebooting the phone and quickly entering V4A before any other apps load. If you can't do that the apps will start to crash leading to the phone being unusable until another reboot. Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not compatible with OxygenOS but you can give a try to Custom ROMs like CM13